# Joomla in Windows is catching my access to a Virtual Directory where I placed my MVC application

Tags: iis, joomla, virtual-directory

In our windows hosting we use the root (wwwroot) folder to host a JOOMLA website as public website. This is running IIS 7.

Then, we created a virtual directory called "App" to host there a ASP.NET MVC4 application.

When I enter `www.mydomain.com` it shows the joomla website correctly.
When I enter `www.mydomain.com/App/` it somehow access my MVC app... as I see the URL changing to `www.mydomain.com/App/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fApp%2f` BUT shows a 404 Joomla error as if it were looking that URL in Joomla.

BTW, the hosting has 2 ASP.NET IIS Setup options: 4.0 Classic and 4.0 integrated.
Using the Integrated one... it displays a blank page... using the classic one shows the 404 Joomla page.

Any idea where to look for this?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the problem.

The Virtual Directory's web.config was inheriting the Joomla's web.config rules.
So, I wrapped all the setting in Joomla's web.config in:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
  <webserver>....
  ...
  <system.web>...
</location>
```

And this way my ASP.NET MVC application just uses its web.config "uncontaminated".